# Openlayers How would i get a hover label over my polygon

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, polygon, maps

make a hover/mouseover label for a polygon in Openlayers?

I made a map with draw, delete and drag polygon function.

Now I need to make a hover mouseover for this.

How to get a hover label for polygon

```
        var polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon Layer");

        map.addLayers([wmsLayer, polygonLayer]);

        polyOptions = {sides: 40};
        polygonControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(polygonLayer,
                                        OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon,
                                        {handlerOptions: polyOptions} );

       var myStyles = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                pointRadius: "${type}", // sized according to type attribute
                fillColor: "#ffcc66",
                strokeColor: "#ff9933",
                strokeWidth: 2,
                graphicZIndex: 1
            }),
            "select": new OpenLayers.Style({
                fillColor: "#66ccff",
                strokeColor: "#3399ff",
                graphicZIndex: 2
            })
        });

         var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(polygonLayer, {hover: true});
        map.addControl(select);
        select.activate();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: 5/13/2015. Updating links. Thank you @Dennis-van-Schaik

Hover

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/highlight-feature.html

Popup

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/popupMatrix.html

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/sundials.html

Comment: I actually just wanted an alt image hover label for my polgonLayer

Comment: @CaptDragon I managed to get a hover effect, But how do I get a label when i hover. A simple label? Your help is always greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: thanks alot, found a way to put text on mouseover in the styleMap

Comment: @BlakeLoizides : I'm interested in something similar. Can you tell me how you managed t o put text on mouseover ?

Comment: @Sergiu - use the same SelectFeature control, and set hover:true when you create it.  Now you have an on-hover handler, not just an on-click handler.

Comment: Links are broken. Use these links for examples:

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/highlight-feature.html
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/popupMatrix.html
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/sundials.html

Comment: @DennisvanSchaik thank you.  I updated the post with your new links.

Answer (score 6):

The SelectFeature control provides event hooks for this purpose:

```
var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
  polygonLayer, {
    hover: true,
    onBeforeSelect: function(feature) {
       // add code to create tooltip/popup
       popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
          "",
          feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
          new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
          "<div>some text here</div>",
          null,
          true,
          null);

       feature.popup = popup;

       map.addPopup(popup);
       // return false to disable selection and redraw
       // or return true for default behaviour
       return true;
    },
    onUnselect: function(feature) {
       // remove tooltip
       map.removePopup(feature.popup);
       feature.popup.destroy();
       feature.popup=null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**OpenLayers v.6:** [How do I handle mouseover for features in OpenLayers 6](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388396/how-do-i-handle-mouseover-for-features-in-openlayers-6/419749#419749)

(Answers above refer to OL2 (question is *tagged* with openlayers-2, but title of question is generic) so it may help someone the same answer for version 6)