# OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud layout broken

Tags: openlayers-2

On https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/19979/19654 i found a solution to add hover / mouseovers to my map:

```
       // add code to create tooltip/popup
       popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
          "",
          feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
          null, //new OpenLayers.Size(320,20),
          "<div>" + feature.attributes['name'] + "</div>",
          null,
          true,
          null);

       feature.popup = popup;
```

Doing this i found the popup don't have a nice / clean layout, see:

[image]

I tried with a fixed size too (new OpenLayers.Size(320,20)) which seems to have the same effect.

So, my question would be if someone has a cleaner/easier/nicer way to improve this? Thanks in advance for any hint on this.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange! I hope you don't mind me mentioning it but your Question comes across as a statement.  To make it obvious what is being asked I recommend that every Question has one (preferably only one) question mark in its Title and Body.

Comment: Chances this problem occurs, because that you changed the css.
Compare you css and openlayers in Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

It is of course a css issue.

I experienced a same issue by making my images responsive with `max-width: 100%;` css instructions on img tag.

I solved my problem specifying max-width value for my specific class/id element, like so :

```
.map img {
    max-width:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[novicegis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/19698/novicegis) suggest to the problem has to do with css. I use OL with jQuery Mobile (1.3.0) but i didn't found any interaction between the style rules of OL and JQM.

After this i found a working example on: http://terokarvinen.com/2012/framedcloud-popup-with-textfile-openlayers

Calls the popup with:

```
    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken",
    feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
    new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
    content,
    null, true, onPopupClose);
    feature.popup = popup;
    map.addPopup(popup);
```

It use a size for the image. I also found the OL css will be injected by javascript where i insert it in the project before the javascript.
After remove the css from source and  install the latest version of OL (2.13) it works.
Maybe the problem was `../img/cloud-popup-relative.png` was unreachable or corrupt.