# How do I handle mouseover for features in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers

I am migrating a project from an earlier version of OpenLayers to v6+.

In the previous version I added 'event handlers' to the marker. I have changed the code to the code below and whilst JS does not complain nothing happens.

```
var marker = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(lonlat),
    id: myid,
});

marker.setId(myid);                

var icon = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(({        
        size: size,
        offset: offset,
        src: 'image.png',
        id: myid
    }))
});            
marker.setStyle(icon)

markers.push(marker); // markers is an arry

markerSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: markers
});

markersLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    id: 'Markers',
    source: markerSource,                
    zIndex: 50
});
map.addLayer(markersLayer);
markersLayer.setZIndex(50);

marker.on('mouseover', function(evt) 
{
     alert('you hovered');      
}, null)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: That's greatly different (and more complicated imho) now, see an example at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-hover-features.html

Comment: Is this a new question? I don't see any relation with the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed in version 6 things are a bit different. As can be found in the [examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-hover-features.html), you can use this:

```
map.on('pointermove', function (e) {
  if (selected !== null) {
    selected.setStyle(undefined);
    selected = null;
  }

  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (f) {
    selected = f;
    f.setStyle(highlightStyle);   //add your style here
    return true;
  });

  if (selected) {
    status.innerHTML = '&nbsp;Hovering: ' + selected.get('name');
  } else {
    status.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
  }
});
```

My two cents about the `selected.get('name')`: you need your Feature to have a property `name` otherwise it will not work. By the standard, a Feature must has type, geometry and properties (but not name!). So I prefer to use the standard, and have the name as a property:

```
const prop = selected.get('properties');
const name = prop?.name;
```

Hope that helps.